# Что возвращает boost::bind?

Tags: c++, boost, bind

Какого типа данных возвращаемое значение `boost::bind`? Я хочу сделать функцию, которая будет принимать в себя результат работы `boost::bind`, но я не знаю какого типа значения он возвращает.

```
void work(int num){
   std::cout << num << std::endl;
}

int main(){
   auto test = boost::bind(work, 5);
}
```

Comment: лучше используйте `std::function` для этих целей

Comment: boost::function<void(int)> test = boost::bind(work, 5);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::bind` сущность шаблонная, и возвращаемый ею тип может (и будет) зависеть от типов передаваемых аргументов. Однако, если же вы хотите привязаться к определённому варианту, то на помощь приходит `decltype`. [Пример](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n69Zmv1IJuUl7iQC):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

void work(int num){
   std::cout << num << std::endl;
}

void f(decltype(boost::bind(work,int())) arg) {
    arg();
}

int main() {
    auto test = boost::bind(work, 10);
    f(test);
}
```

Я специально указал `int()` в `f`, чтобы показать, что зависимость именно от типа, а не от значения.

При этом самая идея того, что нужно опираться на результирующий тип `boost::bind` кажется мне сомнительной.

Comment: А если я хочу чтоб функция была универсальна и принимала любой boost::bind?

Comment: @DenverToha почему тогда не просто любая callable сущность?

Comment: А как сделать так, чтоб была любая callable сущность?

Comment: @DenverToha в комментах писали уже про `std::function`, например.

Comment: так std::function же вроде используется для конкретных сигнатур функций, я не моуг передать туда любой обработчик

Comment: @DenverToha я думаю, что вам стоит в каком-то отдельном вопросе максимально чётко описать чего же действительно хочется. Просто чтобы не раздувать тут слабосвязанную дискуссию в комментариях.